# Draw a simple dotted line or dashed line in OpenGL GLES20 android using fragment shader and GL_LINE_STRIP

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader

I went through different sources and seen that we could draw a dotted line using a fragment shader. Because I am new to OpenGL I couldn't able to understand.

Can anyone share some code sample that plot dotted or dashed line using fragment shader and `GL_LINE_STRIP` in Android.

References:

- [Dashed line in OpenGL3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928678/dashed-line-in-opengl3)
- [Dotted back edges of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960627/dotted-back-edges-of-object)

Comment: If you use `GL_LINE_STRIP` then you don't need a fragment shader. But line stipple is not supported in OpenGL ES. See [OpenGL ES - Dashed Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975618/opengl-es-dashed-lines)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will check the code and let you know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenGL ES - Dashed Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975618/opengl-es-dashed-lines)

Comment: Can you give me some clarity how to use below code: gl.glGenTextures(1, texture_id_, stippleTexObj);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, stippleTexObj);      here what is the texture_id_, stippleTexObj need to pass

Comment: GLES20.glAlphaFunc is not working it was deprecated in GLES20

Answer (score 1):

Line stipple is not supported in OpenGL ES.

If you use OpenGL ES 1.00, then you can use the approach which is presented in the answers to [OpenGL ES - Dashed Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975618/opengl-es-dashed-lines).
You have to create a 1 dimensional texture (2 dimensional Nx1 texture), and wrap the texture on the lines. The texture has a stipple pattern encoded in its alpha channel. The space between the dashes is discarded by the [Alpha test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#Alpha_test).

If you use OpenGL ES 2.00 or higher (OpenGL ES 3.x), then you can't use the alpha test, because it is deprecated. You have to use a fragment shader and to skip fragments by the [`discard`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) keyword.

Create a texture with a red color channel only. The stipple pattern is encoded in the red color channel, but the code is very similar to that one from [OpenGL ES - Dashed Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975618/opengl-es-dashed-lines), beside the fact that you have to use `GL10.GL_RED` for the internal texture format (instead of `GL10.GL_ALPHA`):

```java
byte arr[] = new byte[] { 255, 0, 0, 255 };
ByteBuffer textureBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr);

gl.glGenTextures(1, texture_id_, stippleTexObj);
gl.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, stippleTexObj);
gl.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RED, 4, 1, 0,
                GLES20.GL_RED, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);
```

When you draw the lines, the you have to use a shader program, that discard the fragments dependent on the red color channel of the texture. A very simple GLSL ES 1.00 shader (for OpenGL ES 3.00) may look as follows:

Vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec2  inPos;
attribute float inU;
varying   float vU;

void main()
{
    outU        = inU;
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
precision mediump float;

varying float     vU;
uniform sampler2D u_stippleTexture;

void main()
{
    float stipple = texture2D(u_stippleTexture, vec2(vU, 0.0)).r;
    if (stipple < 0.5)
        discard;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
}
```

Ensure that the texture coordinates which are associated to the vertices are aligned to integral values when you draw the line, that causes the the lines start and end with a dash:

e.g. a quad with bottom left of (-0.5 -0.5) and to right of (0.5, 0.5) and the texture coordinates in range [0, 5]:

```non
 x     y       u   
-0.5f -0.5f    0.0f
 0.5f -0.5f    5.0f
 0.5f  0.5f    0.0f
-0.5f  0.5f    5.0f
```

Since the wrap function is `GL_REPEAT` and the texture coordinates are in range [0, 5], 5 repetitions of the stipple pattern are wrapped to each edge of the quad.

[image]

---

<sub>Instead of using a texture, you can also generate the stippling in the fragment shader. See the solutions for desktop OpenGL cor profile:

[glLineStipple deprecated in OpenGL 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017176/gllinestipple-deprecated-in-opengl-3-1/55088683#55088683)

[Dashed line in OpenGL3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928678/dashed-line-in-opengl3/54543267#54543267)</sub>

Comment: Here what is inU? what have I to give input for this parameter? It will be helpful if you give some example

Comment: @SubhashKumar `inU` is the 1 dimensional texture coordinate. See the table in the answer. Your question in the comment suggest me that you are missing some basics (in OpenGL and unsing Shaders)